# how render latex in stimulsoft report

Tags: c#, latex, stimulsoft

I have a  html page  include `latex` format text,
use `mathjax` to render `latex` in html page, but in `stimulsoft` reoprt  when **"Export as pdf"** or **"Word or Xps"** not work.
How to render `latex` in to actual math when **"Save as pdf"** in `stimulsoft` report

Answer (score 0):

The Latex is not supported in Stimulsoft Reports.